# installing drivers from a file

Tags: drivers, wireless, dongle

i have a usb wifi dongle from a local company and i have downloaded the drivers from the company and after extracting the zip file it looks like this

```
tree ./
./
├── 1.ico
├── autorun.apm
├── autorun.exe
├── autorun.inf
├── desktop.ini
├── Linux
│   └── 2011_0719_RT3070_RT8070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_RT2070_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO.bz2
├── Mac
│   └── RTUSB D2870-1.2.4.0a UI-1.6.8.0_2008_12_04.dmg
├── User Manual.pdf
├── Win CE
│   ├── 091204_RT2870_WinCE6.0_P1.4.9.0.7z
│   └── RT3070 2070 2770 WinCE5.0.zip
└── Windows
    └── Setup.exe

5 directories, 11 files
```

there is no information about linux in the user manual. the bz2 file in the Linux folder just has a file in it called `2011_0719_RT3070_RT8070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_RT2070_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO`. can someone guide me on how to install these?

Comment: The starting point is knowing what OS/release you're using, and if it's a Ubuntu LTS release, which kernel stack you're using, as *drivers* are actually kernel modules, thus the kernel stack you're using can make a *significant* difference. You provided no OS/release details, let alone kernel stack. What I see in your provided details is only a *tarball*, where the instructions are provided (a) inside the tarball itself, or (b) where it's downloaded from; as it's a standard from the early 1980s thus has hundreds+ of standard ways of achieving the result!

Comment: FYI:   It's likely that tarball will be of no use to use today; it'll be intended for kernels of *long ago* just like Windows CE is... but  *tarballs* are the same in GNU/Linux as per windows, or DOS in the before-windows days; having been a standard before both windows & Linux itself.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You should post the results of `lsusb` terminal command so that we can help (while dongle is connected)

Comment: Read `User Manual.pdf`

Comment: It is quite unlikely that this circa-2011 package will compile on any recent; that is, not end-of-life Ubuntu version. Drivers for almost every rt3xx device are already included. If your device is not working immediately, start a new question and include: `lsusb`.